# Density Plots for Unrelated data

Tags: matlab

I have data `x,y = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6]` and a vector `g = [1; 2; 3]` I will like to have a scatter plot of (x,y) with each point colored according to the magnitude of its associated `g` value.

Comment: What have you already tried and what hasn't worked? What functions have you looked at?

Comment: So... `xy = rand(100,2); g = rand(100,1); scatter(xy(:,1), xy(:,2), 20, g, 'o')` ? See [`scatter`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the `scatter` function, you can provide a argument for the color of each dot. The color could be a matrix `npoint x 3` describing a RGB value for each point, or a `npoint x 1` vector, in which case, color is derived from the current colormap.

Therefore, you can simply use :

```
scatter(xy(:,1),xy(:,2), 70 ,g ,'filled')
colormap('gray')
```

`70` represent the size of the circle, `'filled'` fills the circle so you can see properly the color.